# ARM Ubuntu won't let me change my resolution

Tags: raspberrypi, arm

I know this question has been asked at least twice, but I downloaded the 64-bit version of Ubuntu onto my Raspberry Pi 4. I looked at a few tutorials but I couldn't find anything that worked for changing my screen resolution. It decided to set my resolution to 1824 x 984 (9:5)
I have no clue how to fix this. Could the smart people of AskUbuntu please help me? I have the official version from the Ubuntu website. I have used `lsb_release -a` to find my version and it says I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.
I have used xrandr but the results are very strange:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1824 x 984, current 1824 x 984, maximum 1824 x 984
default connected primary 1824x984+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1824x984       0.00* 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ xrandr --output default --mode 1920x1080
xrandr: cannot find mode 1920x1080
```

What do I write as the display? I have never used Ubuntu before and help would be appreciated. I don't even know how to change the file `/boot/firmware/usrconfig.txt`

Comment: Please click [edit] to let us know which release number?  Please do not use Add Comment; Comments are a channel from us to you, whereas the Question should contain all the facts you have about the issue.

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem and this is how I fixed it. Open a terminal window and type

```
    nano /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt
```

(note you will need to run it with sudo, alternatively use any text editor). Then you can add the settings to set display resolution. Mine looks like this:

```
    # Place "config.txt" changes (dtparam, dtoverlay, disable_overscan, etc.) in
    # this file. Please refer to the README file for a description of the variouszn

    # configuration files on the boot partition.

    [HDMI:0]
    hdmi_group=2
    hdmi_mode=82
    hdmi_drive=2

    [HDMI:1]
    hdmi_group=2
    hdmi_mode=82
    hdmi_drive=2
```

Note the two groups HDMI:0/1 this is because RiP4 has two hdmi outputs and they can be configured individually. Also see that the hdmi_group=2 refers to computer monitors, 1 would be for television screens. `hdmi_mode=82` refers to my resolution which is 1080p 60Hz. To find a full list of mode numbers that corresponds to resolutions and rates, you can go here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

Refer to `hdmi_mode` section.

Once these changes are made, you can restart.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I had to use xrandr add mode and newmode calls to add a new resulution and activate it.

Comment: Worked, but the display contrast became low.
The background black turned into a white-ish black, and I haven't understood why.
Maybe something to do with scaling?  Anyone know?

Comment: Can confirm this solution still works for Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
% xrandr -q
```

to list the available modes to pick from.

Comment: This doesn't work and still returns message `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default`